# How to run Fedora container on Ubuntu host?

Tags: fedora, lxc, systemd

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 and was trying to run a Fedora container.  The container I created via given templates does not work properly.  I guess the reason is that `systemd` is not set up correctly.

First, I installed `lxc` on the host. Then I create a Fedora container with

```
# lxc-create -t fedora -n fedora
```

Then start the container

```
# lxc-start -n fedora
```

Unlike other containers, the Fedora container did not automatically get an IP address

```
# lxc-ls -f
NAME     STATE    IPV4        IPV6  GROUPS  AUTOSTART  
-----------------------------------------------------
centos   RUNNING  10.0.3.213  -     -       NO         
dropbox  RUNNING  10.0.3.222  -     -       NO         
fedora   RUNNING  -           -     -       NO
```

I use `lxc-attach` to enter the Fedora container and found the only running process is `init`.  It could get an IP if `dhclient` is executed.

```
[root@fedora ~]# ps x
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/init
   12 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash
   90 ?        R+     0:00 ps x
```

Shouldn't `dhclient`, `openssh-server` and other necessary services start automatically by `systemd`?  Any advice/experience about a Fedora container on Ubuntu/Debian host is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firsteval, you created the `fedora` container twice : your first command is sufficient to download and create a fedora container from [linux containers images](http://images.linuxcontainers.org/images/).

Secondly, I'm betting than apparmor is messing up with your container's cgroups mounpoints. You should see apparmor denying this in `/var/log/kern.log`. Adding `lxc.aa_profile = unconfined` to your container's configuration in `/var/lib/lxc/fedora/config` is a *"quick & dirty"* way to make it start.

Then you will have an IPv4 address attributed by the dhcp daemon.

After this you can dig a bit more in apparmor's lxc profiles and set up something relevant to avoid your containers to run without protection on the host.

Comment: Thank you, it works.  
As the duplicated methods of creating a container might be misleading, I delete one of them.

Comment: And advised by [lxc-users](https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-users/2014-October/007907.html), `lxc.kmsg = 0` is also necessary for the container to work properly.

Comment: The reason why I list two method is when I create a centos container, `lxc-download` template leads to the same problem while `lxc-centos` won't.